# Single application custom Android ROM

Tags: java, android, android-source, rom

I find this question a couple places on the web, but never with a good answer. Let me be specific in the questions asked.

I want to build a custom Android ROM which only features one app. This app is not to interact with any hardware (per now). This app will be launched on the start up of the device. No locked-screen. The device will have to restart if the app malfunctions.

[A resource](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=813093) told me that you can change the *launcher app* of the ROM.

-> Does this mean that the home screen, the one which displays all apps on our phones, is merely another app? If so, can you simply change the launcher app as it is stated here? What were to happen if this app fails?

If this is the case, it would solve the entire issue.

If not, how do you go about making this sort of project? It includes

- Making an app on AOSP
- Refuse users to leave the app or interact with anything else
- Making this app part of the boot-up process
- Remove locked screen
- Make the app a dependency of the OS (to force shutdown if malfunction)

Thanks in advance for any replies

Comment: try kiosk mode policy https://www.manageengine.com/mobile-device-management/single-app-lock-kiosk-mode-mdm.html?network=g&device=c&keyword=%2Bandroid%20%2Bkiosk&campaignid=9226232338&creative=415805416740&matchtype=b&adposition=&placement=&adgroup=93572283556&gclid=Cj0KCQjw09HzBRDrARIsAG60GP95QBVwdLCIIzwgfHfpDNLiRS-TK_8Zov8DQ2wPpw3ieWqXYWhSGDgaAm9MEALw_wcB

Comment: Kiosk mode is broken with Google Assistant under MDM.  Google Assistant allows unauthorized users to break kiosk containment.  Unless there is a Google Account associated with the device, it cannot be disabled.  There is no DPC API policy that disables GA.

Answer (score 0):

I just found Android have a topic about [dedicated devices](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices) (formerly called corporate-owned single-use, or COSU) are a subset of company-owned devices that serve a specific purpose. maybe that can meet your requirement.

BTW, After into the sub-topic [lock task mode](https://developer.android.com/work/dpc/dedicated-devices/lock-task-mode?hl=en) that mentions about set DPC whitelist APPs and the device policy controller (DPC) needs setup by other steps....   FYR~